# get variable from inside function for use outside function

Tags: javascript, amazon-advertising-api

I'm trying to get a returned variable from inside a function and us it in the rest of the page, i'm getting no luck at all, is there a way to get "AmazonvastTagUrl" from inside the function, outside the function, so as I can use it later down the page?

this what have so far:

```
var AmazonvastTagURL = 'https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?cust_params='
console.log('%cAdysis%c Amazon AdTag:', "background: rgb(19 177 118);color:#FFF;padding:5px;border-radius: 5px;line-height: 10px;", "", AmazonvastTagURL);

// Request Bids 

apstag.fetchBids({
    slots: [{
      slotID: 'SOMESLOT',
      mediaType: 'video'
      //Slot name created in the portal, aligns to individual request for this bid 
    }],
    timeout: PREBID_TIMEOUT / 1.5
  },
  function(bids) {
    console.log('%cAdysis%c Amazon Pre-Roll Bid Logs', "background: rgb(19 177 118);color:#FFF;padding:5px;border-radius: 5px;line-height: 10px;", "", bids);
    // console.log('%cAdysis%c Amazon Pre-Roll Bid Logs', "background: rgb(19 177 118);color:#FFF;padding:5px;border-radius: 5px;line-height: 10px;","", encodedQsParams);
    //Pass bids into the function that will append the key values onto the VAST tag 
    setTimeout(() => {
      handleVideoBids(bids);
    }, 100)
  });


function handleVideoBids(bids) {
  if (bids.length > 0) {
    AmazonvastTagURL += bids[0].encodedQsParams;

    console.log('%cAdysis%c Amazon encodedQsParams Params:', "background: rgb(19 177 118);color:#FFF;padding:5px;border-radius: 5px;line-height: 10px;", "", AmazonvastTagURL);
  }
};
```

this get the log out of
[image]

Comment: got an example, as that what i put above works for "inside the function" it consolue logs the results

Comment: You've got a function with no name (which should be a syntax error), then two functions with the same name. It's not clear what's going on, but I have the suspicion that you're trying to call some asynchronous service to set up the value of a global variable, which is a very common mistake (because you really can't do that).

Comment: just edited it, as had a duplicate in

Comment: Why use `setTimeout()`?

Comment: why dont you just return it? return AmazonvastTagURL

Comment: @Vishal That won't work, it's an async function.

Comment: @Barmar declare a variable above fetchbids function, return it so you have something like  'myVariable = handleVideoBids(bids)'

Comment: @Vishal That won;'t work, `bids` is local to the callback function in `fetchbids()`.

Comment: @Vishal  I dont know how to "just return", I aint very good at this stuff,  this?: function handleVideoBids(bids) {
  if (bids.length > 0) {
   AmazonvastTagURL += bids[0].encodedQsParams;
     return AmazonvastTagUrl
  console.log('%cAdysis%c Amazon encodedQsParams Params:', "background: rgb(19 177 118);color:#FFF;padding:5px;border-radius: 5px;line-height: 10px;","", AmazonvastTagURL);
  } 
};

Comment: @Barmar if you have a variable and you assign it the value at this point 'myVariable = handleVideoBids(bids)' inside timeout function, why wont it work ? The only need is that myVariable should be declared at the top. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: See the linked questions. The assigned variable won't be available after the call because it runs asynchronously. @Vishal

Comment: @Barmar what the solution then, baring in mind i aint no good at this stuff, so an example would be highly appreciated

Comment: @Barmar so declare it near var AmazonvastTagURL  as 'var myVariable=null'. Then it will hold the value wont it?

Comment: @Vishal You're not understanding the general problem of async code. The callback doesn't run until all the synchronous code finishes. So it sets the variable *after* you try to read it.

Comment: @DavidStanton See the linked questions.

Comment: @Barmar but you handleVideoBids in the timeout. Why cant you retrieve the value in it by returning it from the function and setting it to a file level variable?

Comment: @Vishal Because the callback runs asynchronously. It runs *after* the function has already returned, so its return value isn't used.

Comment: @Barmar  all those other questions/ answers are complete "foriegn language" to me, i not got a clue, I aint any good at this stuff, a simple example is about the only thing i can follow, my brain aint got that capacity unfortunatly

Comment: @DavidStanton  as per the logs 'AmazonvastTagURL' is updated. What is the issue?

Comment: @DavidStanton It's simple. Anything that needs to use the response immediately must be in the callback. You can set the global variable as well, but its updated valiue won't be available immediately. You can use it in other event listeners, which will run later when the user performs some interactions.

Comment: i need to take AmazonvastTagURL returned values and use later down the page, outside the function

Comment: @Barmar its simple if you know what your doing, as In brain surgery is simple if you know what your doing, as said 3 times, I dont, examples are things I "can follow"

Comment: @DavidStanton at the top declare a variable 'var returnedBids= null'  then set 'returnedBids = bids' below the callback 'function(bids) {' and above 'console.log('%cAdysis%c....' . That should give you access to bids data

Comment: If you do `button.onclick=function() {console.log(AmazonvastTagURL); }` you'll see that clicking the button displays the value of the variable as desired.

Comment: @Vishal  dont seem to work:function(bids) { 
  returnedBids = bids
  console.log('%cAdysis%c Amazon Pre-Roll Bid Logs', "background: rgb(19 177 118);color:#FFF;padding:5px;border-radius: 5px;line-height: 10px;","", bids);
  // console.log('%cAdysis%c Amazon Pre-Roll Bid Logs', "background: rgb(19 177 118);color:#FFF;padding:5px;border-radius: 5px;line-height: 10px;","", encodedQsParams);
    //Pass bids into the function that will append the key values onto the VAST tag 
    setTimeout(() => {
      handleVideoBids(bids); 
    }, 100)
});

Comment: @DavidStanton I think it should work because otherwise data would be lost for updated  AmazonVastTagURL from this line 'AmazonvastTagURL += bids[0].encodedQsParams;' as well

Comment: it dont work, its wont consolue log out furtehr down the page

Comment: i think the problem is that amazon has a variable of bid, which is actually getting consolue logged with:console.log('%cAdysis%c Amazon Pre-Roll Bid Logs', "background: rgb(19 177 118);color:#FFF;padding:5px;border-radius: 5px;line-height: 10px;","", bids);   this shows an "array" or params not just the one need which is encodedQsParams